# Recursive CTE / transitive closure in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transitive-closure

[image]

**My scenario:**

- User A is (fraudster).
- User B is not (fraudster). However, the system will not allow user B
  to do any action. Because B and A are using the same Phone
  Number(Shared attribute with Fraud User). (1 layer).
- User D is not (fraudster). But D is using the same Deviceid with B
  and B is sharing attribute with fraud User. Then block User D as
  well. In this case, there are 2 layers. D compare with B, B compares
  with A.

I can do that using Recursive CTE. However, My supervisor asked me to find an alternative way for that :(.

**Recursive CTE Code:**

```
with recursive cte as (
      select ID, Email, MobileNo, DeviceId, IPAddress, id as tracking
      from tableuser
      where isfraudsterstatus = 1
      union all
      select u.id, u.email, u.mobileno, u.deviceid, u.ipaddress , concat_ws(',', cte.tracking, u.id)
      from cte join
           tableuser u
           on u.email = cte.email or
              u.mobileno = cte.mobileno or
              u.deviceid = cte.deviceid or 
              u.ipaddress = cte.ipaddress
      where find_in_set(u.id, cte.tracking) = 0
     )
select *
from cte;
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Hmmm can I do that using Python ? I am thinking about pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import functools
df = pd.DataFrame({'userId':
                       [1, 2, 3, 4,],
                   'phone':
                       ['01111', '01111', '53266', '7455'],
                   'email':
                       ['aziz@gmail', 'aziz1@gmail', 'aziz1@gmail', 'aziz2@gmail'],
                   'deviceId':
                       ['Ab123', 'Ab1234', 'Ab12345', 'Ab12345'],
                   'isFraud':
                   [1,0,0,0]})
```

Comment: what is the expected output of your shared dataframe?

Comment: @sammywemmy All of them to be fraudsters :).

Comment: Why? Because of the identical email?

Comment: because it shares attributes with fraudsters user  @Roy2012 . User 1 is a fraudster. User 2 is sharing the same phone with User 1 (User 2 becomes a fraudster). User 3 is sharing the attribute with User 2 (email). User 4 is sharing the same deviceId with user 3.

Comment: I'm not sure why 'userid=2' is not a fraud.

Comment: IMHO when looking at `df` data all users are fraudsters, but comments may refer also to provided screenshot where data is diffrent and user identified by 'F' is not a fraudster.

Comment: @r-beginners okay imagine this scenario: User A tried to make something on my website. I have set him as fraudsters. Then he creates a new account (userid = 2). however, he used the same phone. In this case, the new account is fraudsters as user A

Comment: @ipj only userid = 1 is a fraudster. the other are shared attributes. i am looking for something that returns to me they are shared attributes. so i will delete them or block the accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution. It basically calculates the transitive closure of the fraudster users:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'userId':
                       [1, 2, 3, 4,],
                   'phone':
                       ['01111', '01111', '53266', '7455'],
                   'email':
                       ['aziz@gmail', 'aziz1@gmail', 'aziz1@gmail', 'aziz2@gmail'],
                   'deviceId':
                       ['Ab123', 'Ab1234', 'Ab12345', 'Ab12345'],
                   'isFraud':
                   [1,0,0,0]})


def expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, col_name):
    t = pd.merge(no_fraud, fraud, on = col_name)
    if len(t):
        print(f"Found Match on {col_name}")
        df.loc[df.userId.isin(t.userId_x), "isFraud"] = 1
        return True
    return False

while True:
    added_fraud = False
    fraud = df[df.isFraud == 1]
    no_fraud = df[df.isFraud == 0]
    added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "deviceId")
    added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "email")
    added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "phone")   
    if not added_fraud:
        break

print(df)
```

The output is:

```
   userId  phone        email deviceId  isFraud
0       1  01111   aziz@gmail    Ab123        1
1       2  01111  aziz1@gmail   Ab1234        1
2       3  53266  aziz1@gmail  Ab12345        1
3       4   7455  aziz2@gmail  Ab12345        1
```

Comment: ABDULAZIZ - Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: I am getting something else after running ur code: 
PycharmProjects/Mysql/test.py
phone
email
deviceId

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Look at the value of `df`. That's the output.

Comment: Thank you so much. I voted your answer. but it is 80% completed :(. There is something else I hope you can help me with?

Comment: If it answers your question, it would be great if you could accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer and turning it to green. As to helping you with something else - sure. If it's a longer question, it might be best to ask a new question. I promise to have a look.

Comment: Done thanks again, never mind I will give it a try if I was not able to do it. I will ask a question later :).